# Weird bit of js doesnt run in browser console

Tags: javascript

I was doing a tutorial. I know its really basic.
This runs in whatever engine they are using it doesnt run in browser console.

This is the bit

```
let labels = [];
repeat(5, i => {
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
});
console.log(labels);
// → ["Unit 1", "Unit 2", "Unit 3", "Unit 4", "Unit 5"]
```

Like i said it doesnt run. Error: ***repeat is not defined***

Comment: Which tutorial is this?

Comment: https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html
This is the exact page... you can run the code from the buttons next to the snippet

Comment: @lone_wolf32 the definition of `repeat` is given right above. You're supposed to be using it, it's just not present in *every* snippet for brevity.

Comment: right... sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

`repeat` is not a standalone function. It's only used on strings (ex. `"hi".repeat(3)`)

You need to first define `repeat` for your usage like this:

```js
function repeat(n, action) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    action(i);
  }
}

let labels = [];
repeat(5, i => {
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
});
console.log(labels);
```

Answer (score 1):

repeat is not a global function and you should do like this

```js
let labels = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
}
console.log(labels);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `repeat` function in JavaScript natively.

You have to use one of the following loop statements to achieve repeating of instructions:

- `for`
- `while`
- `do - while`

**FOR**

```js
let labels = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
}

console.log(labels);
```

**WHILE**

```js
let labels = [];

let i = 0;
while(i < 5) {
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
  i++;
}

console.log(labels);
```

**DO - WHILE**

```js
let labels = [];

let i = 0;
do {
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
  i++;
} while (i < 5);

console.log(labels);
```